# Get the values between a given range with last value = 0

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I am trying to get some metrics out of a Victoria DB, specifically some printer metrics monitoring the amount of available ink.

What I want to do is extract the metrics which reached 0 (ink is finished) and started from 100 (full ink).

After some research about PromQL, I found that:

1. A range is specified using `delta()` for gauges.
2. A minimum value is specified using `min()`
3. Combining the two (similar to a join in SQL) is done through the operator `*`.

In the end, I have the following query:

`(delta(printer_ink_level_\%)>99) * (min(printer_ink_level_\%) < 1)`

Which however does not return what I want.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are multiplying always by zero when you do `< 1`. Why doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need [ascent_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#ascent_over_time) function from MetricsQL.

For example, the following query will return time series, which increased at least by 100 during the last day:

```
ascent_over_time({__name__="printer_ink_level_%"}[1d]) >= 100
```

If you need obtaining time series, which have zero values during the given period of time, then take a look at [min_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#min_over_time) and [count_eq_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_eq_over_time) MetricsQL functions.